# Can we convert a .ui file back to glade?

Tags: gtk, glade

I have downloaded the source of a project from launchpad for studying. The UI was designed in Glade and only `.ui` and `.xml` files exist in the UI folder.

Can we somehow open it with Glade to see how the developer has designed the UI??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not trying to be a smartass, but the only answer I can give you is "Yes" - just open it in Glade! The only thing I can think of that might be going wrong is that you have a Glade version that is too old. You probably need at least Glade 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Anjuta, It is  a compiling IDE enviroment. 
You can open the *.ui & *.glade file also.